# Entity Framework 6.1.3 when dbContext disposed detached objects are null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, unit-of-work

The below code uses DBContext, and at times I get Subject[] array being null and can only assume that detached objects on disposal of the context has an effect on these same objects making their references null out of the scope the above mentioned. That's when the subject[] array is returned to the caller. In the caller a reference to subjec[] at times returns null. Is this how it should be?

```
public Subject[] GetSubjectList()
{
    using (var dbContext = new DataAccess.TeachersAssistantDbContext())
    {
        _unitOfWork.InitializeDbContext(dbContext);
        return _unitOfWork._subjectRepository.GetAll();
    }
}
```

I was expecting since the dbContext is disposed, the objects get detached, and still should exist within the calling code provided there is a reference to them. I am getting this error with Entity Framework 6.1.3

Comment: Couple of things to note. 1. I am not sure how your `Unit Of Work` object works but at least, you should get back a list of `Subject` entities before your `DbContext` gets disposed. 2. It is not a good idea to pass in a `DbContext` into your `Unit Of Work` that is going to get disposed later (especially if the `Unit Of Work` outlives it). 3. Your `Subject` entities should be fine outside the scope of a `DbContext` provided you don't call any properties that have Dynamic proxies loaded in them that will access the Db. As for why the `Subject[]` is sometimes `null` is not known to me yet.

Comment: Thanks Dandre, my Unit Of Work just composes Repositories that use the same DBContext that is why the dbcontext is injected into it. It baffles me that sometimes it works and other times it doesn't. It was working fine, and now I am consistently getting null exceptions within the calling code. Note also that I am not using the entities in updates but just querying their properties for app consumption. Nothing gets persisted after - of course, because the context has been disposed. So I am struggling understanding what was working before is failing now. And it has become consistent failures.

Comment: could you post the code of the repository GetAll() function? And what does InitializeDbContext() do? The DbSet functions will not return null objects, unless you call FirstOrDefault()/SingleOrDefault() with reference types on an empty sequence.

Comment: @MartinAlexOkello, I think the main point I'm trying to make is that there may be a design flaw in your code and that is causing your code to misbehave. If I get a chance I will post some good articles that will explain what the best practices are for using EF, Repos, etc. But I would second DevilSuichiro about the specifics of your custom methods.

Comment: My reposiories inherit from Abstract Repository with this method in it.       public T[] GetAll()
        {
            try
            {
                return DbContextTeachersAssistant.Set<T>().ToArray<T>();
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

Comment: My reposiories inherit from Abstract Repository with this method in it.

Comment: All I can think of is an exception gets thrown intermittently whilst querying the DbContext, and that returns null according to my code. But why would that exception happen. It has become too consistent that is the problem. So I decided to return an Array instead of the Set<T> initially. As the exceptions were already happening then.

Comment: All I can think of is an exception gets thrown intermittently whilst querying the DbContext, and that returns null according to my code. But why would that exception happen. It has become too consistent that is the problem. So I decided to return an Array instead of the Set<T> initially. As the exceptions were already happening then.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Chaps, I run migrations before, and looks like there was one pending migration that didn't run. I checked, and indeed there was an addition to to the Model, and an Exception was being thrown about migrations expected due to inconsistency between database and dbContext. I have ever since run the migrations and the problem has been resolved. Many thanks for you help though. Someone may end up in this awkward situation without realising the Model Entities changed and not all migrations were run.

Comment: I noticed that you have a `try/catch` around your `Set<T>().ToArray()` and if an exception was raised, it returns `null`. I would recommend that you don't swallow your exceptions like that, especially since it couldn't inform you of the EF error that you had because you didn't run any migrations. Rather let your exception trickle up and be handled in your error handling component / logging layer.